# Airflow:Cannot open Admin UI by specified url

Tags: python, linux, airflow

I've finished installation and configuration of Airflow with no error or warning occured.

While I'm trying to start airflow webservice,something strange were happened.

[click here is the webservice log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3i0Q.png)

4 worker threads are always trying to do something and then exit while there are no error!

At the very beginning, I've considered it as a succeed starting webservice.

But when I'm trying to see what's in the web UI, I just can't open the web page: 110 error time out.

here is my installaion setps and configuration of airflow.cfg,the only difference from the default config is DB url

install:

```
#setuptools install 
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-19.6.tar.gz#md5=c607dd118eae682c44ed146367a17e26
tar -zxvf setuptools-19.6.tar.gz
cd setuptools-19.6
python setup.py build
python setup.py install

#pip install
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/11/b6/abcb525026a4be042b486df43905d6893fb04f05aac21c32c638e939e447/pip-9.0.1.tar.gz#md5=35f01da33009719497f01a4ba69d63c9
......... the same way like setuptools 

pip install paramiko

yum -y install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel

pip install apache-airflow

#wait....
vim /etc/profile
#add the environment variable

airflow db init

airflow webserver
```

Even though I did nothing to change default configuration, by using default SQLite, the webserver seems not working at all...

I've tried several times by removing airflow from pip then install it again.

Even using the official guide, Nothing is going wrong, but, after all, when I started airflow webserver with command

 airflow webserver

 then visit 192.168.18.60:8080(the test server ip + port),there is response 110 time out

the server has no firewall and the port 8080 is clean to run application.

Although I tried command airflow webserver and then visit 192.168.18.60:8080

```
#even I tried this:
 telnet localhost 8080


#it returns:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 193

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bad Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Bad Request</p></h1>
    Invalid Request Line &#x27;Invalid HTTP request line: &#x27;&#x27;&#x27;
  </body>
</html>

#my server do not have any firewall restrictions，all the ports are accessible from outside...
```

so there must be something wrong with my airflow environment...
so I've confused in this situation. I don't know what going on.

Answer (score 0):

ahhhhhh.....problem solved,I forgot to shutdown my VPN, 192.168.18.60 is not accessible from chrome........